How to intentionally leave undefined symbols?
I'm compiling a rust project, and want to include some static with a value not known at compile time, which will only later be linked into a final executable.
I figured I should be able to create some type of ELF object file which holds the entire linked binary except for my static which is waiting to be linked.
I wrote a main.rsfile which has l:
extern "C" {
    static MY_STATIC: u8;
}

I tried using cargo rustc -- --emit obj=out.o, and it rightfully complains that MY_STATIC is undefined. out.o Was emitted regardless so I tried linking that to some .o which has MY_STATIC to see what happens, and it seems out.so has a lot if std stuff still unlinked.

Is that ALL that was in your main.rs, or did you actually have a main program there?  The process you're describing is fundamentally sound.  How did you do the linking?  Did you let rust do it?  It knows how to link the rust standard library.

I had a println to print the static and thats it. I'm assuming that's why its dependent on fmt and std

Sounds like you want partial linking. I.e. you want all the Rust stuff to already be linked together, and only your MY_STATIC to be missing. While this is certainly possible, I don't know if the Rust toolchain supports it easily or if you will need to call the linker yourself with the appropriate option.

Might be a related discussion: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/64191
